# How many pool connection size should be set for a 1000 users Jira system?

Tags: postgresql, connections, connection-pooling, max-connections

For a Jira system, if use Jira's default connection configuration as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jira-database-config>
  <name>defaultDS</name>
  <delegator-name>default</delegator-name>
  <database-type>postgres72</database-type>
  <schema-name>public</schema-name>
  <jdbc-datasource>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://[IP]:5432/jiradb</url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <username>jiradbuser</username>
    <password>{PASSWORD}</password>
    <pool-min-size>20</pool-min-size>
    <pool-max-size>20</pool-max-size>
    <pool-max-wait>30000</pool-max-wait>
    <validation-query>select 1</validation-query>
    <min-evictable-idle-time-millis>60000</min-evictable-idle-time-millis>
    <time-between-eviction-runs-millis>300000</time-between-eviction-runs-millis>
    <pool-max-idle>20</pool-max-idle>
    <pool-remove-abandoned>true</pool-remove-abandoned>
    <pool-remove-abandoned-timeout>300</pool-remove-abandoned-timeout>
    <pool-test-on-borrow>false</pool-test-on-borrow>
    <pool-test-while-idle>true</pool-test-while-idle>
  </jdbc-datasource>
</jira-database-config>
```

In postgresql's config file:

postgresql.conf

```
max_connections = 300
shared_buffers = 80MB
```

In /etc/sysctl.conf file:

```
kernel.shmmax=100663296
```

At test stage, it can work. But in the production environment, for 1000 users use this system, if one app server serve 500 users, how many pool connection size is good to set in the postgresql.conf file?
And, if use pgbouncer, how many connections it can be reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how many cores you have on your database system, how many concurrent I/O requests it can handle and what the ratio of active versus idle time is while the application is using a connection.

I would start with a maximum of 20 sessions.

Comment: 2 cores. I don't how to find out how many concurrent I/O requests. Also, how to get the ratio of active versus idle time?

Comment: To find out how much I/O your system can take, you have to know the storage system. The idle time ratio is hard to figure out. Your best bet is to play with the session maximum and see when you can exhaust the database's resources. Set the limit somewhere below that.

Comment: Using SSD now. This site is good to calculate configuration items: https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/

Comment: The site will give you a random number for `max_connections`. You'll have to test.